# Bubble sort doesnt sort last number with this algorithm

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

I am having issues the last number in this code is not being sorted.

```
   // This is the more advanced optimzed version of bubble sort
        int modifiedBubbleSortArray(int array[])
        {

        int swapped = 0;

         do {
            swapped = false;
            // We specify a loop here for the sorting
            for(int i=0;i<NUM_ARRAYS;i++)
            {
                // We specify aother loop here for the sorting
                for(int j=0;j< i - 1 /* <<< here we make less comparisns on each pass each time */ ;j++)
                {
                    // If the array i is better than j we enter this swap
                    if (array[j]<array[j+1])  
                    {
                        // We swap here for the functions
                        swap(array[j], array[j+1]);
                        // We measure the amount of times we swap
                        amountOfSwaps += 1;
                        // If we swapped we break out of the loop
                        swapped = true;
                    }
                }
            }
             } while (swapped);
        printArray(array);
        return amountOfSwaps;

        }

        // Here we swap values to sort them
        void swap(int & value1, int & value2)
        {
            // We specify a temp and use it to swap
            int temp=value1; 
            value1=value2;
            value2=temp;

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner loop should be:

```
if (array[j]>array[j+1]) 
{ 
  // We swap here for the functions 
  swap(array[j], array[j+1]); 
  // We measure the amount of times we swap 
  amountOfSwaps += 1; 
}
```

Give that a shot and see if your variant on bubble sort sorts correctly.

To sort in descending order, just change the if condition:

```
if (array[j]<array[j+1])
```

One more bug is the inner for loop. Change that to:

```
for(int j=0;j<=i-1;++j)
```

Update (based on last change with swap test added):

```
bool swapped = false; 

// We specify a loop here for the sorting 
for(int i=0;i<NUM_ARRAYS;i++) 
{ 
    // We specify aother loop here for the sorting 
    for(int j=0;j<=i-1;++j)
    { 
        // If the array i is better than j we enter this swap 
        if (array[j]<array[j+1])   
        { 
            // We swap here for the functions 
            swap(array[j], array[j+1]); 
            // We measure the amount of times we swap 
            amountOfSwaps += 1; 
            // If we swapped we break out of the loop 
            swapped = true; 
        } 
    } 
    // If no swaps this iteration, break out
    if (!swapped)
        break;
}
```

If you really want a good sort, look into [introspection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introspection_sort) - a variant on quick sort. The algorithm is more complicated, but the sort is also more efficient, being O(N log N) instead of O(N^2) which is the complexity of bubble sort.

Comment: `if(array[i]>array[j+1]) 
   { 
     // We swap here for the functions 
     swap(array[i], array[j+1]); 
     // We measure the amount of times we swap 
     amountOfSwaps += 1; 
   } `

I think you meant i in the first two but now it doesnt sort the first number.

Comment: No, I meant exactly what I said. Give it a shot. The variable i should only control the number of iterations of the inner loop. The variable j is the one actually responsible for the reordering.

Comment: Okay lmfao this is interesting let me try.

Comment: Well now it sorts in ascending order i want it to go from highest to smallest so i should change the +1 right?

Comment: I changed it to `if(array[j+1]>array[j]) swap(array[j+1], array[j]);` But not its still not sorting the last number..

Comment: I've updated my answer to answer your comment with regard to highest to smallest. Also, if you change the inner for loop as indicated, it should all be sorted properly.

Comment: Did you make the latest change in my answer (j<=i-1)

Comment: Is my method for ending swapping once we swapped enough good?

Comment: Glad to be of help! With regard to the swap test, it looks good. If on a pass the array is ordered, stop iterating further... The only thing you should change is to put the swap test inside the for loop controlled by the i variable. Let me update my answer...

Comment: Awesome because my method was to have least amount of swaps possible and to kill the swap at a certain point so we dont continue looking more times making it quicker faster and optimized.

Comment: @mystycs: I feel obliged to point out that this "optimization" of bubble sort has been pretty well known for quite a while -- but the overhead it imposes keeping track of whether you've done a swap usually ends up greater than what it saves, so it's generally slower than the "unoptimized" version.

Comment: Actually the last fix you gave me does not sort the last one agian.

Comment: @myst it looks like you're trying to adapt my answer from your other question to you're current function. Note that applying it like this isn't going to work -- you have 3 nested loops now and the outter most do.. while essentially isn't doing anything. It would probably be more helpful to you to stop for a moment and visualize the steps that happens when the algorithm is running. Otherwise it's easy to lose sight of what the blob of code is doing or what you're trying to get it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Dears friend (mystics)

below code is written in java ,
but this is the perfect eg. of BubbleSort Algorythm.

```
    int[] nums = { 12 , 5 , 16 , 9 , 25 , 3 , 45 , 11 , 14 };
    int temp;

    for(int y = 1 ; y < nums.length - 1 ; y++) {

        for(int x = 0 ; x < nums.length - y ; x++) {

            if(nums[x] > nums[x+1]) {

                temp = nums[x];
                nums[x] = nums[x+1];
                nums[x+1] = temp;

            }
        }
    }
```